# It is not possible to set the style of the button react-native

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to cross-platform development. I created the button component, but I can not set the style for it. Such an impression that the button does not read into my code. Here is an example of how I create buttons in the code

```
<Button
      style={{fontSize: 15, width:345, height: 75, marginTop:10,
        borderRadius:10, borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#fff'}}
      styleDisabled={{color: 'red'}}
      onPress={() => this._handlePressContinue()}
      title="Continue"
      color='rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'
      backgroundColor="black"
    >
    </Button>

    <Button
      style={{fontSize: 15, width:345, height: 75, marginTop:10, color: 'green'}}
      onPress={() => this._handlePressForgotYourPassword()}
      title="Forgot Your Password"
      color='rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'
    >
    </Button>
```

and I get two white buttons one next to the other. Only the title, the title color and the handler are changed. Any help in the decision or advice will be very much appreciated. Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5h8k.png)

Comment: please add code for your button component

Answer (score 0):

It is highly recommended that you do not user inline styling and instead use a separate constant to enter styles and apply it to your elements. Also it is recommended to user the Stylesheet provided by 'react-native' library. Below is a small demo code(From react native docs).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class LotsOfStyles extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text style={styles.red}>just red</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  myTextStyle: {
    color: 'blue',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    fontSize: 30,
  },
  red: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});
```

This might not be the issue you are facing right now, but if you refactor your code to this method, you can get it working I guess.

Comment: Thank you! I will edit my code, and will follow this style in the future

Answer (score 0):

I decided my problem. Maybe to that that it will be useful: I created a component of the button with the help of

```
<Button
    style={styles.forgotPass}
      onPress={this.GetValueFunction}
      title="Forgot Your Password"
      color='rgba(0,0,0,0.2)'
    >
    </Button>
```

as soon as I used the component TouchableHighlight, everything worked. Here is an example

```
<TouchableHighlight
    style={styles.forgotPass}
    onPress={this._onPressButton}>
      <Text>Forgot Your Password?</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
```

Thanks to everyone who helped